# msdeploy could not authorize when user is local admin

Tags: msdeploy, http-status-code-401

My msdeploy script is suddenly throwing 401 unauthorized errors after a password change on the my webadmin account.  The script I'm using is:

```
msdeploy.exe -source:package='[MyPackage].zip' -dest:auto,ComputerName='[MyServer]',UserName='[MyWebAdminUser]',Password='[MyWebAdminPassword]',IncludeAcls='False',AuthType='Basic' -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -allowUntrusted -retryAttempts=2 -setParam:'IIS Web Application Name'='[MyApp]'
```

In terms of trouble shooting:

- The web admin account is a local admin on the target machine
- All the appropriate accounts have full control of the target directories
- I've checked the web management service settings (which haven't changed) and they appear to be correct
- I've checked that my deploy script is unchanged

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Web Deploy event log on the remote server to be sure, but it sounds like the password has expired for one of these three accounts: your admin user, WDeployAdmin or WDeployConfigWriter

The WDeploy* users aren't meant to expire, but some domain policies enforce it. If it is indeed one of those, you might need to use my blog entry to reset the passwords in IIS: http://blog.richardszalay.com/2013/08/02/manually-creating-wdeployadmin-and-wdeployconfigwriter/

Comment: I'm seeing an empty Web Deploy log on the local server.  Is there anywhere else I should look in the event log?  What should I look for?

Comment: @JeffreyABecker The local server event log is irrelevant. Take a look at the log on the _remote_ server.

Comment: Sorry, Local server is probably a bad choice of words.  On the server which is the Computer in the dest option, I don't see anything particularly relevant.  I'd expect a logon failure for the WDeployAdmin/ConfigWriter users but I dont see those.

Comment: @JeffreyABecker - Actually, login failures will be in the security log.

Answer (score 0):

So, the ultimate problem was many-fold

1. The passwords had expired on the WDeploy* accounts
2. The AD structure had an undocumented change where usernames across domains now have to be fully qualified in the @domain.com format.
3. The MyWebAdminUser password was changed to include a string which broke the powershell script